# Objective-C URL encoding issues

Tags: objective-c

I am creating a URL string like so:

```
[Items appendString:[object objectForKey:@"Items"]];
[Items appendString:@"*"];
[Items deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([Items length]-1, 1)];
//This returns this: ~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 25% of CONTRACT*~SEWER/FLATWORK SUPPLY & INSTALL - 75% of CONTRACT*SUMP PUMP PIT

//add Items to URL
NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://example.com?Items=%@, [Items stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but it returns like so:

```
Items=~SEWER/FLATWORK%20SUPPLY%20&%20INSTALL%20-%2025%25%20of%20CONTRACT*~SEWER/FLATWORK%20SUPPLY%20&%20INSTALL%20-%2075%25%20of%20CONTRACT*SUMP%20PUMP%20PIT
```

how do I get it return like this:

`%20%26%20` instead of `%20&%20` for the `&` ?

Comment: why don't you use `NSMutableURL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the method tries to be too clever - it only does as much as is necessary to get a legal URL and because you don't have a question mark in your string, it probably thinks it is OK to leave the ampersands in.

Try constructing the whole URL and do the escaping on the whole URL.

```
NSString *fullURL = [[@"https://example.com?Items=" stringByAppendingString: items]                       
                      stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or perhaps use [stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:](http://stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
fullURL=[fullURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
NSLog(@"fullURL: %@ ...", fullURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes() for getting UTF8stringencoding of characters

```
NSString *urlString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) Items, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8))
```